# How to count duplicated items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

```
  ourProblems = Db.Problems.GroupBy(m => m.Title).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
            .Select(s => new  ProblemsModel.Problems
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                Name=s.Name,
                Text=s.Text,

            })
```

So here I get duplicated items but I need the number with this one if there is 5 duplicated items it only gives me the name. I want it to give me `5 items you have`

edit working;

```
 ourProblems = Db.Problems.GroupBy(m => m.Title)
            .Select(s => new  ProblemsModel.Problems
            {
                Id = s.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                Name = s.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                Text=s.FirstOrDefault().Text,
                CountItem=s.Count(),



            })
```

Comment: Why don't you use SQL Database aggregate function Count()? Also, please add more details and specify the Database and .NET Language that you use. Best regards,

Comment: because I use select and it gives error if I use count with select. I am trying to get same items and show like you have 3 milks @AlexBell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to eliminate the first `Select` and move the `First` behavior inside the second `Select`. Try something like this:

```
List<problemInstance> ourProblems =  Db.Problems
    .GroupBy(m => m.Title)
    .Select(s => new problemInstance
        {
            Id = s.First().Id,
            Name = s.First().Name,
            Text = s.First().Text,
            NumberOfOccurences = s.Count(),
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: what do you mean by problemInstance inside List<"">. in select part new problemInstance is my viewmodel. but in the list it gives invalid initializer member declarator